# angular ionic - jwt token header post error

Tags: angular, header, ionic3, jwt, wordpress-rest-api

in **ionic v3** i use below codes for communicating with **wordpress api** user by **jwt** plugin

i use bellow code for token validation but it's not work, in other case when i test in **postman** or online request tool validate by this header works so i think it's not relate to server side  :

```
validateAuthToken(token){
    return this.http.post(this.API_USER_VALID, {} , {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}})
      .subscribe((validdata)=>{
        console.log(validdata);
      });
  }
```

**ERROR** :
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtujv.jpg)

for **Login** i use below code and it's work fine 
(by *'Content-Type': 'application/json'* Header **not work** but with *'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'* **work** ) :

```
doLogin(username,password){
    return this.http.post(this.API_LOGIN,"username=" + username +
      "&password=" + password,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
      .subscribe((ddaa)=>{
        console.log(ddaa);
      });
  }
```

i stuck :( , if have a guide please tell me

Comment: Please look up CORS, it is the cause of your issue

Answer (score 0):

Set CORS in your back end and specify headers